# white vs light pink color of MgO

Tags: color

Recently I ordered some high purity MgO, which is light pink in color. However, the old powder I was using was white. MSDS also suggests that it should be white. Can anyone explain the reason of two different colors of MgO of same purity.

Thanks in advance

PS- I suspected it to be due to absorption of moisture earlier, but it is not the case. Even on heating at 800 C, does not change the color.

Comment: There is a proverb saying "When two are doing the same, it is not the same."

Comment: I guess, impurity.

Comment: Could be. but they both have the said purity of 99.95%. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: I've seen bright blue KCl and yellow NaCl. A few ppm of something (not sure it even counts an impurity) can do miracles.

Comment: 99.95% ... Imagine how 500 mg Fe2O3 in 1 kg MgO could look like.

Comment: Small amount can go a long way with color. [Cobalt blue glass](https://www.glassencyclopedia.com/cobaltglass.html) may be colored by as little as 0.02% cobalt oxide. From the link: >Small amounts of cobalt (around,to a ton of glass). Deeper blues are obtained by adding up to ten pounds of cobalt oxide per ton of glass.

Comment: @Poutnik, I was suspecting iron as well. It is not very hard to detect iron by simple tests.

Comment: It is possible, just, that it might be due to band gap states in the MgO crystals themselves. Such states are very common.